# what is wrong with this telnet implementation

Tags: c#, telnet

Im trying to build a small compact telnet tool 
therefor I've decided to tackle the sending without waiting for response  part first

the problem is that no matter which guide I use I just cant make it work

what am I missing here ??

```
public void SendTelnetCommand(string Command , string IPofAP)
{
    IPEndPoint endpoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse(IPofAP), 23);
    TcpClient tcpSocket;
    tcpSocket = new TcpClient(endpoint);

    if (!tcpSocket.Connected) return;
    byte[] buf = System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(Command);
    tcpSocket.GetStream().Write(buf, 0, buf.Length);

    if (tcpSocket.Connected) tcpSocket.Close();
}
```

while debuging I get An unhandled exception of type 'System.Net.Sockets.SocketException' in System.dll

Comment: You do connect correctly? No errors in the sending? No firewalls in the way? Have you checked with a sniffer (like [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/)) on both the client and the server that the data is sent/received?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg yes , manually it works well ( in term of ip and port )
if I use some other tool with same configuration it works well , 
I 'll edit the Q for the results I get , thanks for the feed back

Comment: If you get an exception, I suggest you either catch it and see what it is, or run in the debugger to have it stop on the exception to check it that way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What's the message of the exception? Any inner exceptions? Are you using the correct IP address (IPv4 or IPv6?)? Also, you have to *read* from the stream as well.

However, your issue is most likely using the wrong `TcpClient` constructor. The one that takes the endpoint is a *listener*, not a client. You have to use the hostname + port overload.

That is, try this:

```
public void SendTelnetCommand(string Command, string IPofAP)
{
    TcpClient tcpSocket = new TcpClient(IPofAP, 23);

    if (!tcpSocket.Connected) return;
    byte[] buf = System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(Command);
    tcpSocket.GetStream().Write(buf, 0, buf.Length);

    if (tcpSocket.Connected) tcpSocket.Close();
}
```

You can also use the `IPEndPoint` to connect to a server, however, you have to use the parameter-less constructor, and call `tcpSocket.Connect(endpoint);`

Comment: it still doesn't work but at list it doesn't throws exception 
I'll try to check it further

can you explain why should I read the stream as well ?

Comment: @LordTitiKaka Telnet is "apparently synchronous" (and not just Telnet - you should *always* read when someone is sending you data!). If the other side is sending you data synchronously, you *have* to read it. And most telnet servers send a "Hello" first, so if you don't read it, it will not interpret a single command you send it. Also, are you terminating the command with a `'\n'`? It will wait for an endline before parsing any data. And of course, you might have to login first (read the hello, write username, endline, password, endline).

Comment: I'll edit the code the suit for reading after sending command 
and continue from there :)